# SQL Server DateTime specific format shown below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to show datetime in following format :

2019-02-26T15:59:33.379-05:00

Is it possible to show this in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would be the best type to model that data.

Comment: Date and time data types don't have formats in SQL Server. @Igor is right on the data type you should use, but if you need to display it in a specific way then that should be handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: The *type* should be `datetimeoffset`. Formatting is best done at the client/presentation layer though. If there's a real need to format in SQL, eg in a file export job, you can use `FORMAT()` and the `'o'` standard format in every supported SQL Server version (2012 and later), eg `select format(sysdatetimeoffset(), 'o')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the `o` standard format includes "ten millionths of a second" (7 digits), instead of milliseconds (3 digits)

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2012 on, you can use the [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function with a [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
select format(sysdatetimeoffset(), 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss.fffK')
-->
2019-02-27T15:02:59.652+01:00
```

Comment: I believe that works in 2012 as well, which means all supported SQL Server editions would work. There's no strict need for a custom format either, the standard `'o'` format returns `2019-02-27T16:04:19.0168152+02:00`